# How to make Line renderer Flat Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is 3d map simulation only and adding feature navigating to selected object

I use AI Navigation and adding line renderer as my guide to the target

If you look at the picture below the line is not flat and I don't know how to make it flat at the surface

This is my code

```
[SerializeField]
private Collectable Prefab;
[SerializeField]
private Transform Player;
[SerializeField]
private LineRenderer Path;
[SerializeField]
private float PathHeightOffset = 1f;
[SerializeField]
private float SpawnHeightOffset = 1f;
[SerializeField]
private float PathUpdateSpeed = 0.25f;

private Collectable ActiveInstance;
private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshTriangulation Triangulation;
private Coroutine DrawPathCoroutine;

private void Awake()
{
    Triangulation = UnityEngine.AI.NavMesh.CalculateTriangulation();
}

private void Start()
{
    SpawnNewObject();
}

public void SpawnNewObject()
{
    ActiveInstance = Instantiate(Prefab,
        Triangulation.vertices[Random.Range(0, Triangulation.vertices.Length)] + Vector3.up * SpawnHeightOffset,
        Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)
    );
    ActiveInstance.Spawner = this;

    if (DrawPathCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(DrawPathCoroutine);
    }

    DrawPathCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DrawPathToCollectable());
}

private IEnumerator DrawPathToCollectable()
{
    WaitForSeconds Wait = new WaitForSeconds(PathUpdateSpeed);
    UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshPath path = new UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshPath();

    while (ActiveInstance != null)
    {
        if (UnityEngine.AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath(Player.position, new Vector3(55.6f, 32.04f, 17.37f), UnityEngine.AI.NavMesh.AllAreas, path))
        {
            Path.positionCount = path.corners.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length; i++)
            {
                Path.SetPosition(i, path.corners[i] + Vector3.up * PathHeightOffset);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Unable to calculate a path on the NavMesh between {Player.position} and {ActiveInstance.transform.position}!");
        }

        yield return Wait;
    }
}
```

[image: ty]

Answer (score 0):

That's a general issue that there is only the option to align to the `Z` axis

But - even though it is a bit uncanny - you can simply rotate it and modify the line positions accordingly so it basically aligns with the local Z axis, but you rotate it so it again aligns flat with the world Y axis

So basically

- rotate the LineRenderer object to `-90` on the X axis
- set it to align view with `Z`
- then when assigning positions simply switch them so that `(x, y, z)` -> `(x, z, -y)`

Using a little extension for this

```
public static class Vector3Extensions
{
    public Vector3 FlipForLine(this Vector3 v)
    {
        return new Vector3 (v.x, v.z, -v.y);
    }
}
```

You could do

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length; i++)
{
    Path.SetPosition(i, (path.corners[i] + Vector3.up * PathHeightOffset).FlipForLine());
}
```

though in general it is cheaper to have a single call to `SetPositions` passing the entire array at once.

---

*Typed on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: When adding your suggested method `FlipforLine`, line renderer is not showing